# SSRS Chart Group by Dataset

Tags: reporting-services, dataset, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a chart in SSRS where I use data from two different datasets. Currently I have 2 values from dataset 1 and 2 values from dataset 2 but they are all grouped up into 1 category. Is there a way to group the data by datasets so I can display the data seperately?

Below is the table. The first row is data set 1 and the second row is data set 2
[image: Table]

This is the chart I already have. I want to bring the dataset 2 values 3.45% and 29.27% in its own group and separate it from dataset 1 data on the same axis.

[image: Chart]

Comment: maybe give us a sample of both datasets and a picture of the chart you are building.

Comment: @Daniel The table and the chart has been added

Comment: Do you have access to change the query portion of this report? Combining data within SQL is almost always the quickest / easiest way that I've found.  For example, use a UNION for the two datasets and a static value column to differentiate the datasets.

Comment: @Daniel Yes I have full control over the query, how would I use the static value to separate it into different groups?

Comment: @Daniel nvm i get what your saying now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will see some visual differences because I'm using 2016, but the theory of the chart building is the same.

[[image: SQL Query]]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfX1h.png)[[image: Chart]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJzF6.png)

Can you confirm if this is the chart that you are trying to build?

Here is a picture of how I setup the chart properties:

[image: Chart properties]

Comment: Yes that is the chart im trying to build

Comment: Okay, well your query will be more complicated than my simple SELECTs, but the concept is the same.  Add a static column to each side of the UNION and do a "Series Group" on that static value.  Hopefully that gets you down the right path.

Comment: One small thing that is off in my situation,  The first row in the data should be dataset1 h54rh0001 .61(under participation), .29(under column improvment). Next row: dataset2 flex .08(under participation), .03(under column improvement)

Comment: Also it is summing 29.47 and 2.45%